# Mysql: Reduce length/size in data in Column type Blob

Tags: mysql, sql, blob

I have a database with with data and I have a table that contain a column type LongBLOB, this column has values that take up a lot Mbs. ( up to 5Mbs)

When I run my app program and load this data, My program takes a long time because the column type 'LongBLOB' weighs many megabytes.

In my DataBase have 12K photos.

How I can reduce the size/length of photos automatic form?

Comment: Don't load the photo into your app.  Or only load the photos that you need.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No no, this is not the problem. I have a DataBase with 12K photos save in LongBlob, but this photos take up a lot of space, each photo is minim 1Mb, I want to reduce your size for the photos take up less space. I want to do from automatic form.

Comment: @Arkan6 . . . That is not a database problem.  That is a photo compression problem.

Comment: Ok, then will I have change them manually? anything solution?